# How to get the delegated Approver Email address?

Tags: apex, soql, list, approval-process

I have logic in my custom code where I need to send an email to the custom approver and its delegated approver. But I am not able to get the email id directly in SOQL.

```
List<Account> lstAcc = [Select id, approver1__r.Email, approver1__r.DelegatedApproverId, approver1__r.DelegatedApprover.Email from Account];
```

Is it possible to get the delegated Approver email directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. Еhere is an old idea [Add DelegatedApprover.Name to User object](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ky4rAAA). I can just guess, that this field was intended to be polymorphic and maybe was intended to reference groups as well. Let's wait for the community guru to have a look at it.

For now, you have to use 2 separate SOQL queries to get the needed info.

```
List<Account> lstAcc = [Select id, approver1__r.Email, approver1__r.DelegatedApproverId from Account];

Set<Id> delegatedApproverIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Account acct :lstAcc){
    delegatedApproverIds.add(acct.approver1__r.DelegatedApproverId);
}
delegatedApproverIds.remove(null);

Map<Id, User> delegatedApprovers = new Map<Id, User>([
    SELECT Id, Name, Email
    FROM User
    WHERE Id IN :delegatedApproverIds
]);

for(Account acct :lstAcc){
    // this is the email of delegated approver for approver 1
    String approver1DelegatedApproverEmail = delegatedApprovers.get(acct.approver1__r.DelegatedApproverId).Email;
}
```